# Call a variable within a python sqlite execute function.

Tags: python, list, sqlite, loops

I am trying to create several tables through a loop. To do this I will need a table name which will change when creating each table. I am trying to do this by having a list that adds a character onto the table name.

I have then tried to include the variable inside the execution of an sqlite command.

However I have been getting this error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "TABLEformI": syntax error

Here is my code:

```
def createFormGroups(dbFileDir, csvFileDir):
    groupNumber = input('Enter the number of groups you want')

    conn = sqlite3.connect(dbFileDir)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    currentTable = 0
    while currentTable != groupNumber:
        currentTable = currentTable + 1

        nameGroupList = ['form']
        nameGroupList.append('I')
        nameGroup = ''.join(nameGroupList)

        createGroupTable = cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE''' + nameGroup + '''(ID integer PRIMARY KEY, Gender text,Postcode text,SEN text,Rank integer,FirstChoice text,SecondChoice text,ThirdChoice text,Avoid1 text,Avoid2 text)''')

        conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Can you spot any problems within my code.

Comment: you need a space between "CREATE TABLE" and the table name.

Comment: like this '''CREATE TABLE ''' + nameGroup

Comment: It works but the addition of 'I' after every iteration of the while loop doesn't work. Do you know why? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `formI`, `formII`, `formIII` as the table names?

I would suggest:

```
nameGroup = 'form' + 'I' * currentTable
```

Now don't ask for those to be normalized roman numerals.